# Installing symbolic package in octave in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, octave

I have installed octave with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:picaso/octave
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Then from octave I used the following command:

```
pkg install -forge symbolic
```

I got the following error:

```
configure: error: SymPy version 0.7.5 or later is required
checking for sort... /usr/bin/sort
checking for GNU coreutils... yes
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking python module: sympy... yes
checking for SymPy version... 0.7.4.1
checking for gawk... gawk
pkg: error running the configure script for symbolic.
error: called from 'configure_make' in file /usr/share/octave/4.0.0/m/pkg/private/configure_make.m near line 79, column 9
```

I installed python sympy with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sympy
```

I restarted the operating system and tried again but still the same error.

Comment: As it says, SymPy version 0.7.5 or later. `python-sympy` is 0.7.4.1. You might have to do `pip install --user sympy` or something.

Comment: I got sudo: pip: command not found

Comment: So install pip and try again.

Comment: i got E: Unable to locate package pip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just hit the same problem. The solution is to check if you have pip

```
sudo apt-cache policy python-pip
```

which should return either:

```
python-pip:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.4-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.5.4-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.5.4-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

meaning it isn't installed. Or:

```
python-pip:
  Installed: 1.5.4-1ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.5.4-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.4-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.5.4-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

if it is installed. If not installed run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Now you can run pip to get the new sympy

```
pip install --user sympy
```

Finally back to octave to run

```
pkg install -forge symbolic
```

or

```
pkg install /PATH/YOU/DOWNLOADED/TO/symbolic-2.2.4.tar.gz
```

if you downloaded the tar of the version you need.

Last and final step: Each time your run octave, you need to load the `symbolic` package,

```
pkg load symbolic
```

or you can put this command in your `~/.octaverc`.

Comment: one more thing when i write syms('s') i get error: 'syms' undefined near line 1 column 1

Comment: Each time you open octave you need to load the package in: `pkg load symbolic`

Comment: ok but what should i use to make laplace transformation?

Comment: We are getting very off topic here. I would suggest asking these questions in another forum, I will answer this one last question,  First set t to by symbolic with `syms('t')`, then run a Laplace transform on an equation in terms of t such as `H=laplace(sin(t))`

Comment: Ok so i did all this but still get errors:Symbolic pkg v2.9.0: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 28, in <module>
AttributeError: '_PrintFunction' object has no attribute '__globals__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in octoutput_drv
  File "<stdin>", line 54, in octoutput
  and more that i cant put here ...

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install octave-symbolic
```

Comment: i run this comment success. problem not solved.